# Remove the 'and' between the last and second last authors in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to make my `biblatex` references match [this Vancouver style guide](http://guides.lib.monash.edu/ld.php?content_id=14570618). After some tweaking, my `biblatex` references are almost exactly how I want them, with one exception. The word `and` is inserted between the last and second last authors.

How can I remove the word 'and' between the last and second last authors?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% nejm style gets us close.
\usepackage[style=nejm, terseinits=true]{bib latex}

% This bit makes sure the last names come before the initials.
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

% This puts the volume number in parentheses.
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
    \printfield{volume}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
    @article{kenkre_simple_1997,
      title = {Simple Solutions of the {{Torrey}}–{{Bloch}} Equations in the {{NMR}} Study of Molecular Diffusion},
      volume = {128},
      url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1090780797912167},
      number = {1},
      journaltitle = {J. Magn. Reson.},
      author = {Kenkre, V. M. and Fukushima, Eiichi and Sheltraw, D.},
      urldate = {2017-02-07},
      date = {1997-06},
      pages = {62--69},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
    Here is a reference \parencite{kenkre_simple_1997}.
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: reference-example]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can redefine `\finalnamedelim`, but note that it is language dependent. So you have to use `\DeclareBibliographyExtras`:

```
\documentclass{article}

% nejm style gets us close.
\usepackage[style=nejm, terseinits=true]{biblatex}

% This bit makes sure the last names come before the initials.
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

% This puts the volume number in parentheses.
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
    \printfield{volume}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\addspace}%
}

\begin{document}
    Here is a reference \parencite{yoon}.
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How does one discover tricks like that?

Comment: @daviewales In this case is was simply reading/searching in the `biblatex` manual.

Comment: I've found all the puzzle pieces in the `biblatex` manual now using a text search, but I doubt I would have ever pieced them together myself!

Comment: @daviewales I do not say, that you should have find it. I only tell you, what I've done. But I already know, that `biblatex` has configuration features for almost everything. And I have some experience in using LaTeX (but not a lot in using `biblatex`).

Comment: I don't think it is `\finalnamedelim` that is language specific (expect for `spanish.lbx`). `\finalandcomma` which is used in `\finalnamedelim` is language specific. In your MWE the `\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}` is not needed.