# Remove "and" between authors in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I'd like to remove the "and" between the authors in my bibliography. Currently, I have authors listed as such `author1, author2, and author3` and `author1 and author2`.

Desired output: `author1, author2, author3` and `author1, author`

This is my first time using Latex, so while I believe [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371905/remove-the-and-between-the-last-and-second-last-authors-in-biblatex) is helpful, I've been unable to implement it. Since this is also my first post about Latex, I am also open to feedback on how to post a more informative question!

Code below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% --------------- 10 POINT FONT FOR CAPTIONS ------------------
\usepackage[font=footnotesize, skip=0pt]{caption}
% --------------- NY TIMES FONT -------------------------------
\usepackage{times}
% --------------- CITATIONS -------------------------------
\usepackage[super,sort&compress]{natbib}

\usepackage{paralist}
\let\olditem\item
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
  \section*{\refname}
  \let\par\relax\let\newblock\relax
  \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{\olditem}%
  \inparaenum}{\endinparaenum}

\begin{document}

\fontsize{11pt}{11pt}\selectfont
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

And example citation:

```
@article{boyd2011cultural,
  author="Boyd and Richerson and Henrich",
  journal={Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci.},
  year={2011},
  publisher={National Acad Sciences}
}
```

Comment: Off-topic: The `times` package and the `Times Roman` font named for a newspaper; however, this newspaper is the Times of London, not the NY Times.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using the `unsrtnat` bibliography style, I suggest you proceed as follows.

- Find the file `unsrtnat.bst` in your TeX distribution, make a copy of it, and call the copy, say, `unsrtnat-noand.bst`. (Don't edit an original, un-renamed file from the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `unsrtnat-noand.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In the `unsrtnat-noand.bst`, find the function `format.names`. In my copy of the file, this function starts on line 216.
- In this function, find the following line (l. 228, probably):

  ```
                  'skip$
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
                   { "," * }
  ```
- Still within this function, find the following line (l. 232, probably):

  ```
                   { " and " * t * }
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
                   { " " * t * }
  ```

  I.e., delete `and` , but leave one blank space in the first string.
- Save the file `unsrtnat-noand.bst`, either in the folder where your main tex file is located or in a folder that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the second option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` to `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat-noand}` and perform a complete recompile cycle -- latex, bibtex, and latex twice more -- to fully propagate the change in the bib style file.

---

Here's an MWE (minimum working example) that demonstrates the outcome of this exercise.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
   @misc{ab,author="A and B",title="Thoughts",year=3002}
   @misc{abc,author="A and B and C",title="Thoughts",year=3003}
   @article{boyd2011cultural,
      author="Boyd and Richerson and Henrich",
      journal={Proc.\ Natl.\ Acad.\ Sci.},
      year={2011},
      publisher={National Acad Sciences}
   }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[super,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat-noand}

\begin{document}
aaa\cite{ab}, bbb\cite{abc}, ccc\cite{boyd2011cultural}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

`and` is mean to tell `bibliography engine` that those are different authors. You set out come of the look with `\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={((},close={))}}` for example.

```
\usepackage[super,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\setcitestyle{none,open={((},close={))}}
```

to edit word `and` from bibliography  try use `\renewcommand{\harvardand}{,}` or `\renewcommand{\betweenauthors}{,}`.

More about `natbib` can be read from [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) or [reference](https://www.texlive.info/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natnotes.pdf)

Comment: Thank you @Oni! I'm new to Latex so can you please describe where I should specifically implement this? (e.g., does this go somewhere in my renewenvironment or at the bottom near \biobliography?) Also does `authoryear` also apply to `author`?

Comment: I added link to ctan and reference.

Comment: Hm this has not worked for me yet — to confirm, I don't need to edit authoryear since it's the list of author names that I am trying to customize? Also I'd used `bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` so that my citations are listed in the cited order, not alphabetically. In your recommendation, are you advising that I replace my bibliographystyle with abbrvnat or using both `bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` and `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}`?

Comment: You chose one of the style, use `none` instead of `authoryear` to get list in citation order.

Comment: Thank you for the advice about `none`! My authors list is still listing the "and", so I am unsure about what to do. I had previously edited the author key in my bib. Do I need to change anything there?

Comment: Also I notice that `\setcitestyle{none,open={((},close={))}}` puts two parentheses around my citations in text. Perhaps an important clarification is that I am attempting to edit the author list in the bibliography list, not the author list of the citations in text. (I'm not sure what that proper term is but I'm using text as in the main body of text.)

Comment: You can remove or modify `open={((},close={))}`.

Comment: The `\setcitestyle` directive affects how citation call-outs are created. It has *no effect* on how the formatted bibliographic entries look like. The OP loads the `natbib` package with the options `super` (short for "superscript") and `sort&compress`; this indicates that numeric-style rather than authoryear-style citation call-outs are desired.